# User Profile Service - display user domain name

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user

We have set up profile synchronization and user are displayed as "FirstName LastName", but client wants to display user name from AD. What do I have to change in user profile service to display user logon name from AD instead of his first and last name?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to this, but I don't recommend this.. May not be the appropriate answer but this should complete your need...

a) In Central Administration under Application Management select Manage service applications
b) Click on the User Profile Service Application
c) Under People -> Click Manage User Properties
d) Change Name property mapping to map with AccountName field in AD...

NOTE: You will loose the Name information of the user, if you want to keep it with you - you can create New Property and map it to full name of the user...

Comment: Since standard control didn't suit our needs, we finally created new control which reads user account name from profile if exists. We left user properties as is.

Comment: Great, that is excellent solution to your problem!